# Darksky Icons wont show up using Loop

Tags: javascript, api, icons, darksky

I created i HTML canvas tag via loop, and I'm trying to set that tags icon from DarkskyAPI via loop also, but it wont show up.

```
var skycons = new Skycons({"color": "white"});
  skycons.set("icon0", Skycons = x.currently.icon);    //the icon0 is hardcoded on html
  skycons.play();
  console.log(x.daily.data)
  for(i=0;i<8;i++){

    const canv = document.createElement('canvas')
    canv.id = ('icons'+(i+1)) //i added +1 so the increment would be icon1, icon2
    canv.height = 100
    canv.width = 100
    skycons.set('icons'+(i+1), Skycons = x.daily.data[i].icon)     //but if i set the icon, match should be icon1 + x.daily.data[0].icon , icon2 + x.daily.data[1].icon......icon8 + x.daily.data[7].icon.. but the icons wont show up..

    divs.appendChild(canv)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new loop

```
for(y=0;y<8;y++){
    skycons.set('icons'+(y+1), Skycons = x.daily.data[y].icon)
  }
```

and remove that thing from the other loop